# Как найти значения в словарях?

Tags: python

```
[{'id': '383624',
  'created_at': '2021-03-14 09:39:21.854462',
  'updated_at': '2021-03-14 09:39:21.854584',
  'vacid': '1579950',
  'vactitle': 'Менеджер по продажам',
  'vacdescription': 'Мы предлагаем: трудоустройство согласно ТК РФ;гарантированный доход плюс премиальное вознаграждение;возможность работать рядом с домом/местом учебы;регулярное корпоративное обучение;ДМС, страхование от несчастных случаев и тяжелых заболеваний;'},
{'id': '383643',
  'created_at': '2021-03-14 09:39:21.854462',
  'updated_at': '2021-03-14 09:39:21.854584',
  'vacid': '580654',
  'vactitle': 'Менеджер по продажам',
  'vacdescription': 'Мы предлагаем: трудоустройство согласно ТК РФ;гарантированный доход плюс премиальное вознаграждение;возможность работать рядом с домом/местом учебы'}]
```

Даны вакансии каждая вакансия находится в своем словаре, а все эти словари(вакансии) в списке, как мне по ключу ‘vacdescription’ найти значения среди всех словарей где присутствует слово ДМС?

Comment: Вы считаете, что у нас тут у всех память как у аквариумной рыбки? Пересоздание вопроса в абсолютно таком же виде делу не поможет.

Answer (score 1):

в чем сложность пройти по всем элементам массива и найти нужную запись?

```
res = list(filter(lambda obj: 'ДМС' in obj['vacdescription'], data))
```

или

```
res = [obj for obj in data if 'ДМС' in obj['vacdescription']]
```

Comment: Зря вы ответили. Человек даже не удосужился уточнить, ему словари надо найти, или сами значения по ключу из словаря.